# On first click, the CSS3 working but on second click is not working, why?

Tags: jquery, css

I am learning CSS3 (using jQuery and CSS3). If I click the class CSS3 it is working but the second click it is not working.

```
<script src="jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="custom.css">
```

HTML:

```
div id="test"  class="animate">Try me</div>

<div class="fff" style="width:100px;height:100px;background:#4AB72F"><h3>click here</h3></div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".fff").click(function(){
        $("#test,.animate").css({"transition":"all 10s",
                                 "-moz-animation-name":"test", 
                                 "-moz-animation-duration":"1s"});
    });
});
```

CSS:

```
#test {
    width:160px;
    height:200px;
    margin: 100px;
    background:#68C6F2; 
}
@keyframes test{
    from { -moz-transform: translateX(100%) scale(.1) rotateY(90deg);}
}
```

What is wrong with this code?

Comment: Any errors in your console?

Comment: no error but second click not working help me pls

Comment: You should initialise any CSS code you anticipate to modify in jQuery first.

Comment: [this may be helpful](http://css-tricks.com/restart-css-animation/)

Answer (score 0):

it seems to be problem in that: when you clicked second time css properties already set to this values by first click and it is mean you have nothing to do. Try to clear (set to default css values like "none" or "auto") properties and set again it each click.

ps. please use cross browser css, not only mozilla, it will be more simple to help you other people. `-webkit-`, `-o-`, `-moz-`, `-ms-` is all prefixes AFAIK

Comment: how to use none or auto in css tell me pls

Comment: `.css({"transform":"none"});` default values you may find on w3c site, e.g. for tranform http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transform.asp